# A polymorphic object that belongs to a quasi-STI object: object_type is incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, sti

Consider:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def setup
      has_one :address, :as => :addressable
    end
  end
end

class Employee < Person
  setup
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end

# Shouldn't this be 'Employee'? Is it possible to override?
Employee.create.address.create.addressable_type == 'Person'
```

**Edit**: I got confused for a while there. This is not really STI, it's just inheritance, as `Employee` has its own table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bingo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296360/sti-inheiritance-in-rails-issues-with-find):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```